# Pyspark - Display Top 10 words of document

Tags: python, pyspark, nlp, tf-idf

I'm quite new to Pyspark and did a tfidf processing on a dataframe with the following code

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, CountVectorizer
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
wordsData = spark.createDataFrame([(0,"Hello","World","Spark","Is","Awesome","Hello","World"]),(1,["Hello","World","Spark","Is","Awesome","Hello","World"]),(2,["Hello","World"]),(3,["PYTHON", "Is", "Pretty", "Awesome"])],["label","words"])

#hashingTF way
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures")
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
rescaledData.show(truncate=False)
print(hashingTF.indexOf("PYTHON"))
```

Now I want to store the Top 10 words with their tfidf value in a separate column. But since I'm not really used to working with vectors I'm a little stuck on how to achieve this. I know I somehow need to apply the indexOf function to every token of a document to find a mapping to its value, but I don't know how to do it. As far as I understood each vector is built up like this: (Size,[Key],[Value])

I was also thinking of using the CounteVectorizer way (and for that using its vocabulary) but I run in the same problem there.

Anyone who can help?
This is the output so far:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|label|words                                           |rawFeatures                                                     |features                                                                                                                                       |
+-----+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0    |[Hello, World, Spark, Is, Awesome, Hello, World]|(262144,[32755,44691,64441,179674,262052],[2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|(262144,[32755,44691,64441,179674,262052],[0.44628710262841953,0.44628710262841953,0.22314355131420976,0.5108256237659907,0.22314355131420976])|
|1    |[Hello, World, Spark, Is, Awesome, Hello, World]|(262144,[32755,44691,64441,179674,262052],[2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|(262144,[32755,44691,64441,179674,262052],[0.44628710262841953,0.44628710262841953,0.22314355131420976,0.5108256237659907,0.22314355131420976])|
|2    |[Hello, World]                                  |(262144,[32755,44691],[1.0,1.0])                                |(262144,[32755,44691],[0.22314355131420976,0.22314355131420976])                                                                               |
|3    |[PYTHON, Is, Pretty, Awesome]                   |(262144,[61511,64441,191247,262052],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])          |(262144,[61511,64441,191247,262052],[0.9162907318741551,0.22314355131420976,0.9162907318741551,0.22314355131420976])                           |
+-----+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output data, `rawFeatures` and `features` are sparse vectors and it has 3 parts,`size`,`indices`,`value`.

for eg,`(262144,[32755,44691,64441,179674,262052],[0.44628710262841953,0.44628710262841953,0.22314355131420976,0.5108256237659907,0.22314355131420976])`

here
`size = 262144 ,indices = [32755,44691,64441,179674,262052] , values = [0.44628710262841953,0.44628710262841953,0.22314355131420976,0.5108256237659907,0.22314355131420976]`

the indices are index values mapped to hash values of respective word.
from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf
`Our implementation of term frequency utilizes the hashing trick. A raw feature is mapped into an index (term) by applying a hash function. Then term frequencies are calculated based on the mapped indices.`

Now to read output vector and map to word, we can use hash values of each word using same fitted model and map with `features` vector indices and get corresponding values.

1.first we get hashed index values for each word.

```
ndf = wordsData.select('label',f.explode('words').name('expwords')).withColumn('words',f.array('expwords'))
hashudf = f.udf(lambda vector : vector.indices.tolist()[0],StringType())
wordtf = hashingTF.transform(ndf).withColumn('wordhash',hashudf(f.col('rawFeatures')))
wordtf.show()
+-----+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+
|label|expwords|    words|         rawFeatures|wordhash|
+-----+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+
|    0|   Spark|  [Spark]|(262144,[179674],...|  179674|
|    0| Awesome|[Awesome]|(262144,[262052],...|  262052|
|    0|   World|  [World]|(262144,[32755],[...|   32755|
|    0|   Hello|  [Hello]|(262144,[44691],[...|   44691|
|    0|      Is|     [Is]|(262144,[64441],[...|   64441|
|    2|   Hello|  [Hello]|(262144,[44691],[...|   44691|
|    2|   World|  [World]|(262144,[32755],[...|   32755|
|    1|      Is|     [Is]|(262144,[64441],[...|   64441|
|    1|   World|  [World]|(262144,[32755],[...|   32755|
|    1| Awesome|[Awesome]|(262144,[262052],...|  262052|
|    1|   Spark|  [Spark]|(262144,[179674],...|  179674|
|    1|   Hello|  [Hello]|(262144,[44691],[...|   44691|
|    3| Awesome|[Awesome]|(262144,[262052],...|  262052|
|    3|  PYTHON| [PYTHON]|(262144,[191247],...|  191247|
|    3|  Pretty| [Pretty]|(262144,[61511],[...|   61511|
|    3|      Is|     [Is]|(262144,[64441],[...|   64441|
+-----+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+
```

2.flatten output `features` column to get `indices` & `value`.

```
udf1 = f.udf(lambda vec : dict(zip(vec.indices.tolist(),vec.values.tolist())),MapType(StringType(),StringType()))
valuedf = rescaledData.select('label',f.explode(udf1(f.col('features'))).name('wordhash','value'))
valuedf.show()
+-----+--------+-------------------+
|label|wordhash|              value|
+-----+--------+-------------------+
|    0|  179674| 0.5108256237659907|
|    0|   64441|0.22314355131420976|
|    0|   44691|0.44628710262841953|
|    0|   32755|0.44628710262841953|
|    0|  262052|0.22314355131420976|
|    1|  179674| 0.5108256237659907|
|    1|   64441|0.22314355131420976|
|    1|   44691|0.44628710262841953|
|    1|   32755|0.44628710262841953|
|    1|  262052|0.22314355131420976|
|    2|   44691|0.22314355131420976|
|    2|   32755|0.22314355131420976|
|    3|   64441|0.22314355131420976|
|    3|  191247| 0.9162907318741551|
|    3|  262052|0.22314355131420976|
|    3|   61511| 0.9162907318741551|
+-----+--------+-------------------+
```

3.get top n words for each document(label) filtering based on its rank and join both DFs and collect & sort to get the words along with its value.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('label').orderBy(f.desc('value'))
valuedf = valuedf.withColumn('rank',f.rank().over(w)).where(f.col('rank')<=3) # used 3 for testing.
valuedf.join(wordtf,['label','wordhash']).groupby('label').agg(f.sort_array(f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col('value'),f.col('expwords'))),asc=False).name('topn')).show(truncate=False)
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|label|topn                                                                                                                   |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0    |[{0.5108256237659907, Spark}, {0.44628710262841953, World}, {0.44628710262841953, Hello}]                              |
|1    |[{0.5108256237659907, Spark}, {0.44628710262841953, World}, {0.44628710262841953, Hello}]                              |
|3    |[{0.9162907318741551, Pretty}, {0.9162907318741551, PYTHON}, {0.22314355131420976, Is}, {0.22314355131420976, Awesome}]|
|2    |[{0.22314355131420976, World}, {0.22314355131420976, Hello}]                                                           |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Oh wow, brilliant explanation with much clarification! Thank you!

Comment: Amazing this helped me to understand everything.`f.collect_list()` can cause repetitive results and blow the dataset so maybe `f.collect_set()` can be used instead to get distinct result.